# Limits of dataframe size

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bigdata

I am working on a physics problem which requires massive pandas dataframe, might not be the best option.

Basically, I need to run a calculation with 3 inputs, for a lot of different sets of those input values.

My input dataframe looks like this:

```
betas  = np.linspace(0,np.deg2rad(10),100)
thetas = np.linspace(0,np.deg2rad(10),100)
z = np.linspace(0,2,100)

df =  pd.DataFrame(list(product(betas, thetas, z)), columns=['Beta', 'Theta', 'z'])
```

And for each row I need to run calculation, which produces a 100x100 array (x,y coordinates).

If I naively also use `itertools.product(df, x,y)`, it runs out of memory.

Do I loop over each row in my input `df`? Or can I save the output 100x100 (or 10000) array for each row to the `df`?

Is there a better way?

Possible output could be:

df:

```
beta theta z RESULT
0.1   0.1  2  (0, ... , 9999)
...
{million rows like this}
```

Thank you very much, 
let me know if I can give more detail

Comment: In this case the `x` and `y` in `itertools.product(df, x,y)` would be the columns `betas` and `thetas`?

Comment: Use dask library

Comment: Assuming you're dealing with double-precision numbers through, the minimum amount of memory this will take up is 8*100*100*100*100*100 bytes, or about 80 GB. If that fits in memory on your machine (a rule of thumb being that pandas tends to require twice the amount of memory that the raw NumPy array takes up for its operations), you should be good. Otherwise you'll have to perform your operation in batches, the nature of which will depend on what you want to do with your data afterwards.